# Removing tables that don't exist

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have tables that are showing in the left frame of phpmyadmin that are not showing in the right. I'm getting errors in my err file in ssh and I want to remove these tables, they are not linked to anything in the website, they are old tables that need to be removed. How do I remove them?

I've tried ssh, but nothing happens when I use the drop command in mysql.

You can see the facileforms tables on the left, but they do not show on the right. How do I remove them?

I can't post a picture yet, but here is a link to it.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4436859/Screenshot-2014-03-24-12.12.jpg

Comment: Might be an obvious question, but did you try refreshing your view?

Comment: Yes. I've logged out and logged back in again also. There are errors in my mysql error file looking for these. They just need to be dropped, they aren't used.

Comment: If I click on them in the left panel I get Table Doesn't Exist error in phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0):

These kind of situation comes when one of the following cases occurs:

i) Less space available on database server

ii) There is some configuration issue regarding Innodb database

iii) You are trying to copy the database from one location to another in terms of copying db files only

iv) Some server upgrade has been done.

In all the cases the best way to overcome this to create new database and import your sql file into it (if you have backup of it)